# Attempting to connect to azure database has suddenly stopped working, throwing exceptions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have the following code running in an Azure Function (V2);

```
 new DocumentClient(new Uri(keys.dbEndPoint), keys.dbPrimaryKey);
```

Which has worked fine running in azure functions on localhost until today, without changing anything I'm now getting the following exception:

> Data [IDictionary]:{System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} HResult
>   [int]:-2146233036 HelpLink [string]:null InnerException
>   [Exception]:{System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set
>   to an instance of an object.} Message [string]:"The type initializer
>   for 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.UserAgentContainer' threw an
>   exception." Source [string]:"Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core"
>   StackTrace [string]:"   at
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.UserAgentContainer..ctor()\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.ConnectionPolicy..ctor()\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.ConnectionPolicy.get_Default()\r\n
>   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.Initialize(Uri
>   serviceEndpoint, ConnectionPolicy connectionPolicy, Nullable`1
>   desiredConsistencyLevel)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient..ctor(Uri
>   serviceEndpoint, String authKeyOrResourceToken, ConnectionPolicy
>   connectionPolicy, Nullable`1 desiredConsistencyLevel)\r\n   at
>   Platform.AzureConfig.get_Database() in
>   D:\DeansCloud\AzureConfig.cs:line 60" TargetSite [MethodBase]:{Void
>   .ctor()} TypeName
>   [string]:"Microsoft.Azure.Documents.UserAgentContainer" Static members
>   Non-Public members

Which doesn't say much, the inner exception mentions a null reference exception:

Message [string]:"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Is this an issue with azure cosmos db now? Do I need to update something?

Comment: which Functions version are you using? v1 or v2? Also, can you add a bit more code how you instantiate the DocumentClient in your function? Via binding or manually?

Comment: @silent V2 and manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue to be the latest azure core tools, downgrading to version 24 fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating your own DocumentClient, try to use the binding-based version. This will also give you better performance. See an example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/functions-recipes/cosmos-db#using-documentclient) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50546910/1537195).