# Cannot connect to CosmosDB from VS Code Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I created Azure Function (2.0v) from C# HTTP template . Then I added output binding to CosmosDB based on [CosmosDB docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb#output---example):

```cs
public static class AddEvent

{
    [FunctionName("AddEvent")]
    public static void Run(

        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]
            HttpRequest req, 
        [CosmosDB("SomeDatabase", "SomeCollection", Id = "id", 
        ConnectionStringSetting = "myCosmosDB", CreateIfNotExists = true)] 
            out dynamic document)
    {
        document = new { Text = "something", id = Guid.NewGuid() };
    }
}
```

Packages, that I use (csproj file):

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB" Version="3.0.0-beta7" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.11" />
```

This is my local.settings.json. I based them on values from CosmosDB emulator:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "",
        "myCosmosDB": "AccountEndpoint=https://localhost:8081/;AccountKey=C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw=="
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I hit HTTP trigger I get:

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: AddEvent.
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'document'.
Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.UserAgentContainer' threw an exception. 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

What does this exception means? I cannot find any relevant information about it and it completely stops my local work. Function works well without CosmosDB attribute.

Comment: Seems similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562026/attempting-to-connect-to-azure-database-has-suddenly-stopped-working-throwing-e). Which exact version do you have?

Comment: I have version no. 28. But downgrading to 24 didn't help - it resulted with `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB: Method not found: Void Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Config.FluentBindingRule1.AddValidator(System.Action2<!0,System.Type>)'.` error. Unfortunately these two [1](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2598), [2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1648) resolutions don't help as well.

Comment: Issue solved in 29 cli. You could accept one answer to close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be a breaking change in new cli. Try to downgrade cli to `2.0.1-beta.25`, it works on my side. BTW, I recommend you to update `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` to `1.0.13` to avoid possible exception.

`beta.24` seems outdated and also causes `Method not found` error on my side. While `beta.26` leads to error same as `beta.28`.

However, if I debug the project directly using VS(which uses [beta.26 no-runtime version](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/releases/tag/2.0.1-beta.26)) or publish it to Azure, works fine. Have opened [an issue on github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2941), you can track it if interested.

**Update**

Solved in `2.0.1-beta.29`, runtime `2.0.11857.0`.

Answer (score 4):

This was a regression with the latest version (2.0.11776) of the host. This has been addressed and the release is currently in progress.

Answer (score -1):

What version of the DocumentDB package are you referencing?

Recommendation would be to either:

downgrade any DocumentDB nuget to **[1.13.2.](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/700)**

Remove the DocumentDB reference completely and instead directly reference Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB, which will reference the correct version for you.

Comment: I directly use `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB" Version="3.0.0-beta7" />` in my csproj. But it doesn't help.

Comment: OP is using Functions V2, V2 has a higher SDK version than V1 at this moment.